# ¿como mover buttons con el evento teclado?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, eventos

les explico mi pequeño juego requiere que las piezas se muevan cuando uso flechas (solo con el teclado), use button para este programa he intentado una infinidad de métodos pero no funcionan.

¿alguien tiene idea de que método debería de implementar?

```
public void movernegro(Button centro, Button boton) {
     String remplazar;
     remplazar = centro.Text;
     centro.Text = boton.Text;
     boton.Text = remplazar;
     centro.BackColor = Color.Black;
     boton.BackColor = Color.White;
}
        
public void posicionamiento(Button centro, Button boton1, Button boton2) { 
     if (boton1.Text == "16") {
         movernegro(centro, boton1);
     }else if (boton2.Text == "16") {
          movernegro(centro, boton2);
     }
}
       
public void posicionamiento(Button centro,Button boton1, Button boton2, Button boton3) {
     if (boton1.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton1);
     }
     else if (boton2.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton2);
     }
     else if (boton3.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton3);
     }
}
        
public void posicionamiento(Button centro, Button boton1, Button boton2, Button boton3, Button boton4)
{    
     if (boton1.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton1);
     }
     else if (boton2.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton2);
     }
     else if (boton3.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton3);
     }
     else if (boton4.Text == "16")
     {
          movernegro(centro, boton4);
     }
}
private void Randomizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     randomizar();
}
private void posicion1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            
}

private void posicion1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
           if (posicion1.Text=="16")
           {
                 posicionamiento(posicion1, posicion2, posicion5);
                 ganar();
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Por lo que veo lo unico que estas haciendo es reemplazar un botón por otro, y eso no deberia ser así, sino que tendrias que mover un solo botón (que imagino que es la finalidad al final), es cierto?

Comment: creo que no formule bien la pregunta, este es un rompecabezas que usa buttons,  dentro de ellos tienen texto ("1""2"..... ) use un botón de fondo negro para que cuando se mueva vaya reemplazando el botón donde se posiciono.

Answer (score 2):

La mejor manera de mover controles en C# es cambiar su posición dentro de su contenedor (formulario, panel...).

Voy a usar de ejemplo el método **`KeyDown`** del formulario, de esa manera cada vez que pulses una flecha con el formulario activo se movería el botón:

```
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) //Pulsas flecha arriba
    {
        boton1.Top -= 1;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) //Pulsas flecha abajo
    {
        boton1.Top += 1;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) //Pulsas flecha izquierda
    {
        boton1.Left -= 1;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) //Pulsas flecha derecha
    {
        boton1.Left += 1;
    }
}
```

Con este método vas a mover el botón hacia la posición que pulses en el teclado 1 píxel.

Acuérdate de marcar la propiedad del formulario `KeyPreview` como `True`, ya que sin eso no se va a invocar nunca el evento `KeyDown` del formulario.